# chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function(){}) not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, runtime-error, declarative

When I try to remove all rules with chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(), it says:

> Error in response to events.removeRules: Error: Invalid value for
>   argument 1. Property '.1': Value does not match any valid type
>   choices, Property '.2': Value does not match any valid type choices.

This is the code, I just copied it from here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/pageAction/pageaction_by_url/background.js

```
// When the extension is installed or upgraded ...
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function () {
    console.log('installed');
    // Replace all rules ...
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function () {
        console.log('removed');
        // With a new rule ...
        chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([
            {
                conditions: [
                    new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
                        pageUrl: {
                            urlEquals: 'www.google.com'
                        }
                    })
                ],

                actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction(), console.log('hi'), init()]
            }
        ]);
    });
});
```

The weird thing is that the console says (in this order):

> hi 
>   installed 
>   removed 
>   **error above (error in response to...)**

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You have a tiny error, extra comma after `pageUrl`.

Comment: Deleted the comma, it still says the same...

Answer (score 2):

The error originates from your `actions` list in the new rule.

<s>`actions` apparently expects an array of function references</s>

As far as I can tell, the `actions` list in a `Rule` must only contain "actions" provided by the API, and cannot execute arbitrary code. The [base documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events#declarative) is not very clear as to what an "action" is.

However, from the [documentation of `chrome.declarativeContent`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent#rules) (emphasis mine):

> As a declarative API, this API lets you register rules on the `onPageChanged` event object which take an action **(currently just `ShowPageAction`)** when a set of conditions, represented as a `PageStateMatcher`, are met.

So, unfortunately, it seems you cannot use this API to call your `init()`

Comment: It worked for the 'property 2' but it still has this error: 'Error in response to events.removeRules: Error: Invalid value for argument 1. Property '.1': Value does not match any valid type choices.', and it references the .removeRules(undefined, function(){}) line

Comment: Okay, I'm apparently wrong. I don't think you can add arbitrary code as actions - only those defined by the API. I'll delete this answer later. Don't look too much into the line referenced - the error is with the rule.

Comment: P.S. I edited the answer instead of deleting it. You still can't use arbitrary code as actions. The reason for it, I suppose, is that `declarativeContent` API operates at native code level. Therefore, it cannot trigger arbitrary JS code, only predefined things that are also available at native code level.

Comment: Are you sure we can't use arbitrary code as actions? I threw a simple alert in as one of them, and it ran exactly once, but wouldn't repeat when the page changed.

Comment: besides ShowPageAction, there is now SetIcon, since Chrome v39